# Is there a way to know if a column of a Polars Lazy/DataFrame is set as sorted in the python api?

Tags: python-polars

You can use `df.with_columns(pl.col('A').set_sorted())` to say to polars that column A is sorted.
I assume that internally there is some metadata associated to this column. Is there a way to read it ?

I see that polars algorithms are much faster if dataframes are sorted, sometimes I want to be sure that am I taking these fast paths.

Proposal : Is it possible to have a Lazy/DataFrame attribute like `metadata` that would store this type of information.
Something like that:

df.metadata

{'A' : {'is_sorted' : True}}

Answer (score 3):

This information is stored on the `Series`.

```py
>>> s = pl.Series([1, 3, 2]).sort()
>>> s.flags
{'SORTED_ASC': True, 'SORTED_DESC': False}
```

Comment: is there something more direct than something like `{i:df.get_column(i).flags for i in df.columns}` for checking on a data frame?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor you could use `df['A'].flags['SORTED_ASC']`